# How to pick a random item within a list while two lists are being considered?

Tags: python, list, random

Sorry I couldn't come with a better title. My problem is I have two lists and I want to randomly pick an item from first list and match it with an item from second list, but indexes of those items cannot be the same (li1[3] cannot be matched with li2[3]) and also after an item is picked it has to be removed from the list. I tried this code but it doesn't get the job done. Thanks for any help.

```
from random import choice

teams1 = ["brazil", "croatia", "england", "italy", "mexico", "cameroon", "ivory coast", "japan"]
teams2 = ["spain", "germany", "belgium", "holland", "argentina", "portugal", "france", "usa"]


counter = 3
counter2 = 8 
while counter != 0:
    a = choice(range(1,counter2))
    a1 = teams1[a]
    b = choice(range(1,counter2))
    b1 = teams2[b]
    print(teams1[0], b1)
    print(teams2[0], a1)
    del teams1[a]
    del teams2[b]
    del teams1[0]
    del teams2[0]
    counter -= 1
    counter2 -= 2

print(teams1[0], teams2[0])
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the indices of the items being chosen cannot be the same. Are they the indices *after* the items chosen have been removed from the lists or the indices in the original lists?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it straight at first. Basically the thing is, for example, Italy can never be paired with Holland, Croatia can never be matched with Germany etc even after the original list has been modified.

Comment: I think this cannot be done totally randomly, as sometimes the teams are picked in order such that the last ones remaining in each list are the match that needs to be avoided. When that happens, you have to restart the drawing from the beginning. Is that what you want to do? I somehow get a sense that the way you construct the matches as described is not exactly what you need to do, but I don't know the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The teams advance from eight different groups. Two teams advance from each group. One from spot number one, two from spot number two. Let's say, first group promotes 1.Brazil and 2.Spain, second group promotes 1.Croatia and 2.Germany etc. Brazil can't meet with Spain as they've already been together in a group and it can't meet with other teams that have been promoted from spot number one. This is what I am trying to figure out here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `random.randrange`!

```
import random

teams1 = ["brazil", "croatia", "england", "italy", "mexico", "cameroon", "ivory coast", "japan"]
teams2 = ["spain", "germany", "belgium", "holland", "argentina", "portugal", "france", "usa"]

t1 = random.randrange(0, len(teams1))
t2 = random.randrange(0, len(teams2))

while t2 == t1:
    t2 = random.randrange(0, len(teams2))

rand_choice1 = teams1.pop(t1)
rand_choice2 = teams1.pop(t2)
```

The `while` loop prevents the two indices from being identical, and the `.pop()` builtin method of the list removes the teams we choose from the list.

This approach only lists a single matchup, but it could be easily made into a function to randomly match all teams.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be surprised if there is a more elegant way of constructing pair combinations, but this seems to do what has been clarified in the question comments:

```
#/usr/bin/env python2.7
from random import shuffle

def main():

    teams1 = ["brazil", "croatia", "england", "italy",
              "mexico", "cameroon", "ivory coast", "japan"]
    teams2 = ["spain", "germany", "belgium", "holland",
              "argentina", "portugal", "france", "usa"]

    excluded_pairs = dict(zip(teams1, teams2))
    shuffle(teams1) # not really needed
    shuffle(teams2)

    while len(teams1):
        t1 = teams1.pop()
        if len(teams1) > 1:
            if teams2[-1] != excluded_pairs[t1]:
                t2 = teams2.pop(-1)
            else:
                t2 = teams2.pop(-2)
        elif len(teams1) == 0:
            t2 = teams2.pop(-1)
        elif len(teams1) == 1:
            if (teams2[-1] != excluded_pairs[t1]
                and teams2[-2] != excluded_pairs[teams1[0]]):
                t2 = teams2.pop(-1)
            else:
                t2 = teams2.pop(-2)

        print '{} vs. {}'.format(t1, t2)

    print len(teams1)
    print len(teams2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is right. Except that your program exits when there are still values in either lists. That is because your `counter` hits 0 and the condition:

```
while counter != 0:
```

no longer holds.

You can change that condition to check if there are no more items in either lists using:

```
while len(teams1) and len(teams2):
```

or :

```
while counter > -1:
```

and get rid of the last line:

```
print(teams1[0], teams2[0])
```

And your program works as expected.